# Property '$refs' does not exist on type 'void'

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

Trying to auto-focus on the next input field after 1 character is typed.

Getting error: Property '$refs' does not exist on type 'void'.

Here is the function:

```
  setup() {

const autoFocusNextInput = (event, max: number) => {
  if (event.target.value.length === max) {
    const nextElement =
      this.$refs[`input-${Number(event.target.dataset.index) + 1}`];
    if (nextElement) nextElement.focus();
  }
};
```

Here is the template for context:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between">
    <Field
      class=
      type="text"
      name="1"
      maxlength="1"
      ref="input-0"
      data-index="0"
      @input="autoFocusNextInput($event, 1)"
      autocomplete="off"
    />
    <Field
      class=
      type="text"
      name="2"
      maxlength="1"
      ref="input-1"
      data-index="1"
      @input="autoFocusNextInput($event, 1)"
      autocomplete="off"
    />
```

Comment: `this` in setup doesn’t refer to the component instance because it is not even instantiated yet.

Comment: but at the point it does have a concrete instance, `this` will have a value, or no?

Comment: Yes but setup itself has no concept of the component instance.

Comment: you are 100% right. thank you.  Vue2 --> Vue3 learning curve is steep\

Comment: @dp38922 I added an answer. Hope it will help you in understanding the use of this in arrow and regular functions specially when dealing with Vue.

Comment: @Terry It does with `getComponentInstance`, just not in the same way as with `this`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is in arrow function syntax, The arrow function doesn't define its own execution context. `this` value inside of an arrow function always equals `this` value from the outer function.

Vue will bind `this` keyword to the instance so that it will always reference the component instance. Because of this, it's really required to not use arrow functions when defining methods because they always bind `this` to the parent context, which is not actually the Vue instance - but the global object (`the Window`).

**Working Demo with regular function syntax :**

```js
new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  methods: {
    autoFocusNextInput(event, max) {
      if (event.target.value.length === max) {
        const nextElement = this.$refs[`input-${Number(event.target.dataset.index) + 1}`];
        if (nextElement) nextElement.focus();
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
    <input
      type="text"
      name="1"
      maxlength="1"
      ref="input-0"
      data-index="0"
      @input="autoFocusNextInput($event, 1)"
      autocomplete="off"
    />
    <input
      type="text"
      name="2"
      maxlength="1"
      ref="input-1"
      data-index="1"
      @input="autoFocusNextInput($event, 1)"
      autocomplete="off"
    />
</div>
```

Comment: The answer uses Vue 2. The question obviously uses Vue 3

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out but my answer is more about the access of `this` inside arrow function instead of vue versions.

Answer (score 0):

My Vue3 approach to eliminate `.this` keyword.

```
    const autoFocusNextInput = (event) => {
  if (event.target.value.length === 1) {
    const nextInput = event.target.nextElementSibling;
    if (nextInput) {
      nextInput.focus();
    } else {
      event.target.blur();
    }
  }
};


<Field
      class=""
      type="text"
      name="input1"
      maxlength="1"
      @input="autoFocusNextInput($event)"
      autocomplete="off"
      autofocus

    />
    <Field
      class=""
      type="text"
      name="input2"
      maxlength="1"
      @input="autoFocusNextInput($event)"
      autocomplete="off"
    />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can't understand your answer. Please provide more context information